# Html5 - Javascript - sqlite for intranet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite

I need some database functionality for our intranet at work, but I am severely limited in my options. My only scripting tools are JavaScript/JQuery.

I was wondering if it would be possible to use SQLite with html5 and JS/JQ?

Thanks for all the pointers in the right direction!

Desired usage:

I wish to port in a large excel sheet in the db file, and run queries and return row results in the intranet page.

Comment: No, it's not possible to use SQLite with just Javascript alone. What exactly do you mean with "some database functionality"? What exactly are your requirements? How much data do you need to store? Do you need to share it between browsers? What queries do you need to perform on the data?

Comment: YOU CAN! use https://github.com/agershun/alasql

Comment: @Philipp it is possible to use sqlite from the browser. You can use something like bookshelf.js, check http://bookshelfjs.org/#faq although i dont recommend it outside a server enviroment either. The native localStorage will do the job in most scenarios

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, there are some libraries on the web. For example, the library [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) is a port of SQLite to Javascript.

Comment: How would you share data between different clients? Using a file? But then, what about database synchronization? I'm quite curious indeed

Comment: @A.Wolff Two client doesn't have the same data base. You need to synchronize with a server your data base.

Comment: Ya and so this is quite limiting all the purpose of it

Comment: @A.Wolff If your application does not set data and just get data, this library is helpful. Or if you create a local application with one client.

Comment: This would be retrieve only at this point, and quite possible all that will happen with this db

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to solve this problem:

1. There are some packages, which can read data from XLSX file directly, for example: [js-xlsx library](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), where you can retrieve data directly from Excel table (so, you do not need to use SQLite). It takes some time to read whole Excel, but you can keep your XLSX alive.
2. You can install simple node server for your intranet with [SQLite package](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3). This is a fastest way, because the client version of SQL.js loads whole file with database, which can be much bigger than original XLSX file.